# Using google play game service to share data between users?

Tags: android, google-api

I'm an android Developer, and I am thinking of making a game where users may design and exchange levels through a level editor. Not having an own server to store data, I was wondering if this may be done through the Google apis? I can save/load data in the cloud through the new Google game service api, but as far as I know, this seems to be only for the current logged in user. Is it possible to somehow use it (or another Google+ -api) to make a user be able to save their level, and the level will then be public and able to be downloaded by other users (read only), even if the user that made it is not logged in? I must therefore also have some way for a user to search through all levels created by my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Google+ API, but I suggest you take a look at Google App Engine, since your only problem is you don't have your own server and Google App Engine provides you FREE server.

Google App Engine is very easy to use, it supports Java/Python/PHP/Go. There are already a lot developers using Google App Engine and achieved great success. Below is its developer guide:

[Google App Engine Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/)

Comment: I have some experience with Servlets, so it looks like this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Google Game Services API is not designed for sharing data between users besides certain common functionality (such as leaderboards), so to store custom data that is available to all users you would need your own server infrastructure.

It may be helpful to look into [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/overview), which is a Google provided mechanism built on Google App Engine to build highly scalable backends specifically for web, Android, and iOS applications that you can get started with for free. The recent [Google I/O 2013 - From Nothing to Nirvana in Minutes: Cloud Backend for Your Android Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5u_Owtbfew) talk may be a useful starting point.